# Arabic Swift String isn't empty after removing all characters

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code to replace part of a string and remove white spaces:

```
let str = "باب ‏".replacingOccurrences(of: "باب", with: "").trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

print(str.count) /// gives 1 why not 0
```

But it gives me 1 always while it should be 0. Why?

Comment: The string has a RTL mark.

Comment: But it's more complicated than that.

Comment: @Sweeper it appears as white space , how to replace it ?

Comment: It doesn't appear as whitespace. The whitespace you see is a regular space character.

Comment: @Sweeper how to replace it with "" ?

Answer (score 0):

If it's [RTL Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark) (and it probably is), that's "\u{200F}" in Swift. If you want to trim it with the whitespace, you'd just add it to your set. That'd be something like:

```
.trimmingCharacters(in: whitespacesAndNewlines
                            .union(CharacterSet(charactersIn: "\u{200f}")))
```

You can also just replace that directly:

```
.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{200f}باب", with: "")
```

Keep in mind the layout rules, since sometimes bidirectional literal strings like this can get confusing in the editor. You may want to separate the Arabic like:

```
let bab = "باب"
let rtl = "\u{200f}"

string.replacingOccurrences(of: rtl + bab, with: "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the content of your original string:

```
func hexCharactersArray(_ string: String) -> String {
    string.unicodeScalars.map { String(format: "0x%X", $0.value)}.joined(separator: ",")
}

let originalString = "باب ‏"
print(hexCharactersArray(originalString))
```

The result is `[0x628,0x627,0x628,0x20,0x200F]`

```
0x628 - arabic letter beh
0x627 - arabic letter alef
0x628 - arabic letter beh
0x20 - space
0x200F - right-to-left mark
```

The first three are letters, then some whitespace, but 0x200F is a unicode character in the category of control characters.  It's not a letter and it's not whitespace.

When you do:

```
let replacedString = originalString.replacingOccurrences(of: "باب", with: "").trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
print(hexCharactersArray(replacedString))
```

you get `[0x200F]`

Because you've replaced the letters and trimmed out the whitespace, but you've left behind a control character.

If you want to trim that out too, use:

```
let replacedString = originalString.replacingOccurrences(of: "باب", with: "").trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines.union(.controlCharacters))
```